# Evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x+a)\sin(x+b)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Please help me evaluate:
$$
\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x+a)\sin(x+b)}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given integral is: $$\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x+a)\sin(x+b)}$$

The given integral can write:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x+a)\sin(x+b)}=\int\frac{\sin(x+a)}{\sin(x+b)}\cdot\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x+a)}$$

We substition 
$$\frac{\sin(x+a)}{\sin(x+b)}=t$$

By the substition of the above have:

$$\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x+a)}=\frac{dt}{\sin(a-b)}$$

Now have:

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sin(x+a)\sin(x+b)}=\int\frac{\sin(x+a)}{\sin(x+b)}\cdot\frac{dx}{\sin^2(x+a)}=\frac{1}{\sin(a-b)}\int\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{1}{\sin(a-b)}\ln |t|=\frac{1}{\sin(a-b)}\ln|\frac{\sin(x+a)}{\sin(x+b)}|+C$$

Comment: This is supposed to be a homework question, so I presume you should leave the proposer with some room to do it himself...

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Multiply and divide by $\sin(b-a)$.

Further Hint:

> Write $\sin(b-a) = \sin((x-a)-(x-b))$